# How to get my installed lib recognized by R

Tags: r, openssl

To put it simply, my R could not recognize my "libssl.so.1.0.0" installed.
Wondering any one has any suggestion.

For the details:

I was trying to install a R package "devtools", 
but had one issue.

```
install.packages("devtools")

...
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/git2r/libs/git2r.so':
  libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/git2r’
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/httr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/devtools’
...
```

it seemed that "libssl.so.1.0.0" is required.

But when I checked which "openssl" I am using:

```
$ which openssl
~/.anaconda/bin/openssl
$ ldd ~/.anaconda/bin/openssl
                linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb0de8000)
                libssl.so.1.0.0 => /somewhere/Jun/.anaconda/bin/../lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00002b0618dca000)
                libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /somewhere/Jun/.anaconda/bin/../lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00002b0619041000)
                libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003cae000000)
                libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003cad800000)
                /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003cad400000)
```

So it seems to me that "libssl.so.1.0.0" was there, the problem is that R could not find it. 
Any suggestion to solve this?

Update:

Another tempt (following 42-'s kind suggestion in the comments)

Adding `dependencies=TRUE` for "install.packages" command
    install.packages("devtools", dependencies=TRUE)

```
1: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘gmailr’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘lintr’ had non-zero exit status
```

tried to install "git2r" first:

```
install.packages("git2r",dependencies=TRUE)

** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘summary’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘git2r’
Creating a generic function for ‘diff’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘git2r’
Creating a generic function for ‘merge’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘git2r’
Creating a generic function for ‘plot’ from package ‘graphics’ in package ‘git2r’
Creating a generic function for ‘head’ from package ‘utils’ in package ‘git2r’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/git2r/libs/git2r.so':
  libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/host/somewhere/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/git2r’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp55IwjF/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("git2r", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable in `R_HOME/etc/ldpaths` to include the path to your openssl library.

Comment: And either install 'git2r' or set `dependencies=TRUE`. Next time include the code rather than saying 'trying to install a R package "devtools"'.

Comment: @42-. Hi 42-, Thank you for your kind suggestion. Sorry that I did not include the code of "trying to install a R package "devtools"", I did not realize that it could be relevant. I have added the corresponding code, and also I attached the results of my trial of following your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work out. If you have other ideas, or notice something is wrong with my trial, please kindly let me know. TKS!

Comment: @nicola, Hi Nicola. Thank you for your kind suggestion. It is embarrassing, I was trying to find out where is "R_HOME/etc/ldpaths". Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: `R_HOME` is the root directory of your `R` installation. You can find it with `R.home()` in R. Try also `locate ldpaths` from shell to find it (what's your system?).

Comment: @nicola. Thanks very much for your explanation, yes, I could find it following your suggestion. I realized that "etc" actually literally means "etc". I am using CentOS5.